# How to do element wise operation for two tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

Say, I have two Tensors A and B, both with shape [-1, m, d]. How could I get a Tensor C with shape [-1, m*(m-1)/2, d] so than C_ij = A_i + B_j? Where + is an element wise addition. I know there is an element-wise operation named tf.add, but how should I use it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow overloads operators so `A + B` should work.